# system doesn't have any usb boot option Error

Tags: uefi, bootable

I want to install Linux 17 instead of Windows 10. I burned my USB with Rusuf using GPT partition scheme for UEFI. I restart my computer with shift key and choose EFI USB. When computer has restarted itself again error message on screen.

> system doesn't have any usb boot option please select other boot
>   option in boot manager menu

I tried lots of ways in BIOS screen. In my researches, I saw that people change some changes in system configuration in BIOS, but in my computer's BIOS there are no something like that.

SCU options (I guess it should be UEFI):

[image: i.hizliresim.com/2rolBE.jpg]

Secure Boot Option:

[image: i.hizliresim.com/Brbd3L.jpg]

Processor: Intel Atom z3735f

Comment: It would be good to give us at least a hint of your machine details.

Comment: I have edited post. So what now?

Comment: Now you hope somebody smart comes along and helps out.

Comment: You may have 32-bit firmware but are trying to boot 64-bit OS.

Comment: Probably. I have booted my device to 64-bit OS onto which had 32-bit, but it includes BIOS not UEFI.